# git filter branch fatal revision

Tags: regex, git, azure-devops, commit, git-tfs

I'm trying to migrate from TFVC (Visual Studio Team Services) to git (hosted via Visual Studio Team Services). I've been able to build a script which migrates all the stuff, branches, does some cleanup etc.
I used git tfs (https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md) and a few online blog posts.

Everything works like a charm except when I try to cleanup commit messages I get a "fatal: bad revision s/^git-tfs-id:.*$//g" using the command from the doc
`git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/^git-tfs-id:.*$//g"' -- --all`

I've been trying to play around with the regex, it doesn't solve the issue. After digging a lot on the internet I still can't understand why it's not working properly.
I'm using git for windows command line (latest version) and my knowledge of git is pretty basic, but I couldn't find any alternative to achieve what I want to do.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found what the actual issue was... A quote issue
`git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/git-tfs-id:.*//gm"' -- --all`
doesn't work
`git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "sed 's/git-tfs-id:.*//gm'" -- --all` 
works

I guess there is an compatibility issue between the interpretation of quotes of windows command line and Git virtual bash.

Regardless thanks @Giuseppe Ricupero for your help!

Comment: FYI I made a PR which got merged to fix the issue in the official documentation https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/903

Comment: You just made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

The command you're trying to execute rely on an external tool: the `sed` executable (available by default on most unix flavours but not on windows): probably you have to install `sed` on your own.

Get a `windows-compatible` version of `sed` from one of these unix-tools bundles:

1. [UnxUtils](https://www.cygwin.com/) (latest update 2013, medium size)
2. [Cygwin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)   (constantly updated, the default choice if you don't mind about size)
3. [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) (latest update 2010)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I thought the Git for Windows installation would bring some of the tools with it (maybe I checked something wrong during the installation process?)
Does this mean I could technically replace that with some equivalent PowerShell?

Comment: @baywet: This may work but it's untested: ``git filter-branch -f --msg-filter '% { $_ -replace "^git-tfs-id:.*$","" }' -- --all``